# Nav tab color transitions not working in scrollspy component with scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm encountering an issue with color transitions for nav tabs in my scroll-spy component. The tabs are not smoothly transitioning colors as I scroll through the scrollable div. I searched over internet but I am not understanding it as I don't have any knowledge about JavaScript framework JQuery. Any help will be much appreciated. Also can you tell me how to work with bootstrap if encountering error, should find help on internet or should i use other substitute component.

```css
.scrollspy-example h4{
  height:800px;
  background-color:pink;
  
}


 
.click{
  max-height:300px;
max-width:300px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
/*   position:relative; */
}
```

```html
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css"> 


      <div class="row sticky-top">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-1">Item 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
      <div class="col-3">
    <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-2">Item 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-3">Item 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-3">
    <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-4">Item 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="click">

  <div class="col-12">
    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#list-example" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0">
      <h4 id="list-item-1">Item 1</h4>
      <p>...</p>
      <h4 id="list-item-2">Item 2</h4>
      <p>...</p>
      <h4 id="list-item-3">Item 3</h4>
      <p>...</p>
      <h4 id="list-item-4">Item 4</h4>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAn3x.gif)